# How to show radio button checked on edit page using session variable in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have stored the values of variables in session and want to display on the edit page.

My controller code is

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $customer_data=DB::table('customers')->select('*')->where('customer_id',$id)->first();
    $id= $customer_data->customer_id;
    $name= $customer_data->customer_name;
    $phone = $customer_data->customer_phone;
    $email = $customer_data->customer_email;
    $dob = $customer_data->customer_dob;
    $city = $customer_data->city;
    $gender = $customer_data->customer_gender;
   Session::put('id', $id);
   Session::put('name', $name);
   Session::put('phone', $phone);
   Session::put('email', $email);
   Session::put('dob', $dob);
   Session::put('city', $city);
   Session::put('gender', $gender);

   return redirect('/admin/customer-record')->with('popup','open');
}
```

My blade template code is

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <label class="radio-inline radio1"><input type="radio" name="city" value="Prague" @if(Session::get('city') == 'Prague') checked @endif>Prague</label>
    <label class="radio-inline radio1"><input type="radio" name="city" value="Other" @if(Session::get('city') == 'Other') checked @endif >Other City</label>
     <label class="radio-inline radio1"><input type="radio" name="city" value="Toutist" @if(Session::get('city') == 'Tourist') checked @endif >Tourist</label>

       @if ($errors->has('city'))
          <span class="help-block">
             <strong>{{ $errors->first('city') }}</strong>
          </span>
      @endif
      </div>
```

Comment: Does this not work? What's the behavior currently?

Comment: This should work fine unless the session variables are empty.

Comment: can you please print `Session::get('city')` to check the available value?

Comment: @MeeraTank  dd(Session::get('city')) is showing correct value. not check box is not showing checked.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<label class="radio-inline radio1"><input type="radio" name="city" value="Prague" {{ Session::get('city') == 'Prague' ? 'checked' : ''}}>Prague</label>
```

What this does is when the session param city is equal to Prague it will echo checked in the input. If not it wil echo an empty string